# Capitalize HTML title tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, capitalize

I am working on a WordPress site that is using Advanced Custom Fields and the HTML title is in one of the field groups and each new page has a page title entered manually and then output with

`<title><?php echo the_field('custompagetitle'); ?></title>`

For example pages are titled PAGE ONE, PAGE TWO, etc.

I am looking for a way to convert all page titles to Capitalized as in into Page One, Page Two, etc.

I believe the HTML title can not be targeted by css so I have searched here and elsewhere for javascript or other method to achieve this but almost every example I find outputs the to log console or is for other strings and constants but not the page title.

Would appreciate any ideas, thanks

EDIT: This may be due to how ACF processes php because answers posted until this edit don't seem to work. Adding ACF tag as well.

Comment: `<title><?php echo ucwords(strtolower(the_field('custompagetitle'))); ?></title>`

Comment: This doesn't work, perhaps due to how php or Advanced Custom Fields work because it  it does work as a line <?php echo ucwords(strtolower("HELLO WORLD")); ?> inside the body.

Comment: `document.title = document.title.toUpperCase()`

Comment: This changes the page title to uppercase in a php document but I want capitalized and in any case doesn't work when inserted as script into WordPress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code it will work. I have tested this code.

```
<title><?php echo ucwords(strtolower(get_field('custompagetitle'))); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML title tags cant be targeted by CSS but you can mainpulate any DOM elements with Javascript like so..

```
const capitalize=(word)=> {
  return word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1).toLowerCase();
}
let title= document.querySelector('title')
title.textContent=capitalize(title.textContent)
```

Comment: Does this change to upper case or capitalize? As my comment above I am not sure it works on the title tag.

Comment: it works just fine, you can try it your self

Comment: Please see my comment above, same thing happens as in that comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73656388/capitalize-html-title-tag#comment130069263_73656388

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood your question. I have update my answer above and i have add a simple function to capitalize a string. i hope it helps

Comment: Doesn't work still, I will edit my question to add an ACF tag and explanation because this might be ACF specific.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to first lowercase all the words and then convert first letter of each word to uppercase. The following code should work for you:

```
<?php
$title = get_field('custompagetitle');
$title = ucwords(strtolower($title));
?>
<title><?php echo esc_html($title); ?></title>
```

Comment: After adding this I get a critical error. Can't see why though.

Comment: Sorry I have edited my code. The new code works.